# The following code retuns number of rows as zero always

Tags: php

In this code I have used the prepared statement query, I want number of rows but in following code it returns me zero rows. plz tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="lamp";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$contactno=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['contactno']);
$description=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['description']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['contactemail']);

$subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['subject']);
$creationdate=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['creationdate']);
if(isset($_POST['status1']))
{
    $status =$_POST['status1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['noteid']))
{
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['noteid']);
}
$stmt=$conn->prepare("update notifications set subject=?,description=?
,status=?,  creationdate=?,contactno=?,contactemail=? where id=? ");               $stmt->bind_param("ssisisi",$subject,$description,$status,$creationdate,$contactno,$email,$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();  
if($stmt->num_rows >0)
{
    echo "sucess";
    header("Location: updategovermentnotification.php");
}
```

Comment: Try like this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Because `update` wont return `num_rows`

Comment: need to use `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){` instead of `if($stmt->num_rows >0){` because update returns only true or false based on successful execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UPDATE` query returns only `true` or `false` based on successful execution, so you need to do like below:-

need to use `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){` instead of `if($stmt->num_rows >0){`

OR

`if($stmt->execute()){ $stmt->store_result();echo "sucess";header("Location: updategovermentnotification.php");}`

Answer (score 1):

The [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) property you are looking for is [`$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php). It contains the number of rows affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

The property [`$num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) contains the number of rows returned by a `SELECT` query.